# Magento store broken after moving to other folder

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, magento, migration

I had to move my Magento store to another folder on the same server. I did this a couple of times and it always worked fine, but the last time it didn't. The site loads all broken, there's a dash missing in the middle of the links. I can't even login through /admin, cause that page is also broken.

The only thing I remember doing differently is that I turned compilation and css merging on before moving the files.

The store is at http://www.atelieminimalista.com.br/loja/ and, as you can see, the css and images don't load and the links are all weird, with an dash missing. The database definitions are fine I guess, I changed the secure and unsecure link. If you go to admin, it's also weird.

I tried to check htaccess, deleted the cache, but everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely want to manually flush the cache var/cache/ directory and remove the compiled code in the includes/src/ directory or disable the compiler (edit the file includes/config.php and comment out both 'define' lines).